# Cryptocompare Api - understanding API return values

Tags: client, altcoin, trading, historical-trade-data, bitcointalk

I have come across the API from cryptocompare.com which fetches data from various exchanges.

I do not understand the some values returned from the API call

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=INR&e=Unocoin

Questions

1. Difference between LASTVOLUME and LASTVOLUMETO
2. Difference between VOLUME24HOUR and VOLUME24HOURTO
3. Difference between TOTALVOLUME24H and TOTALVOLUME24HTO

   ```
   {
       "RAW": {
   "BTC": {
       "INR": {
           "TYPE": "2",
           "MARKET": "Unocoin",
           "FROMSYMBOL": "BTC",
           "TOSYMBOL": "INR",
           "FLAGS": "2",
           "PRICE": 847591,
           "LASTUPDATE": 1512451304,
           "LASTVOLUME": 0.00139926,
           "LASTVOLUMETO": 1186.00018266,
           "LASTTRADEID": "478501",
           "VOLUME24HOUR": 75.19298754,
           "VOLUME24HOURTO": 61956574.46784429,
           "OPEN24HOUR": 837298,
           "HIGH24HOUR": 860506,
           "LOW24HOUR": 491500,
           "CHANGE24HOUR": 10293,
           "CHANGEPCT24HOUR": 1.2293114279503832,
           "CHANGEDAY": 0,
           "CHANGEPCTDAY": 0,
           "SUPPLY": 16720800,
           "MKTCAP": 14172399592800,
           "TOTALVOLUME24H": 319738.400426581,
           "TOTALVOLUME24HTO": 271005614230.93204
       }
   }
       },
       "DISPLAY": {
   "BTC": {
       "INR": {
           "FROMSYMBOL": "Ƀ",
           "TOSYMBOL": "₹",
           "MARKET": "Unocoin",
           "PRICE": "₹ 847,591.0",
           "LASTUPDATE": "Just now",
           "LASTVOLUME": "Ƀ 0.001399",
           "LASTVOLUMETO": "₹ 1,186.00",
           "LASTTRADEID": "478501",
           "VOLUME24HOUR": "Ƀ 75.19",
           "VOLUME24HOURTO": "₹ 61,956,574.5",
           "OPEN24HOUR": "₹ 837,298.0",
           "HIGH24HOUR": "₹ 860,506.0",
           "LOW24HOUR": "₹ 491,500.0",
           "CHANGE24HOUR": "₹ 10,293",
           "CHANGEPCT24HOUR": "1.23",
           "CHANGEDAY": "₹ 0",
           "CHANGEPCTDAY": "0",
           "SUPPLY": "Ƀ 16,720,800.0",
           "MKTCAP": "₹ 14,172.40 B",
           "TOTALVOLUME24H": "Ƀ 319.74 K",
           "TOTALVOLUME24HTO": "₹ 271.01 B"
       }
   }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VOLUME...TO shows the volume made in INR, and without TO shows volume made in bitcoins.

As one bitcoin is around 750 000 INR, a volume made of 75 bitcoins in last 24 hours is equivalent to volume made  of 61956574 in INR currency.

Comment: what is CHANGEPCT24HOUR and CHANGEPCTDAY?

Comment: also wondering what CHANGEPCT24HOUR. seems inconsistent across currencies for example for 1337 crypto I have CHANGEPCT24HOUR = 15.00 EUR and CHANGEPCT24HOUR = -50.00 GBP? those currencies arent that different in value?

Comment: im thinking this isn't the amount the value of the coin fluctuated in 24 hours? otherwise the api is returning incorrect data